# php 7 spl autoloader not working

Tags: php, php-7, autoload, spl

recently having to migrate from a php 5.3 to a php 7 server, and i am running into a perplexing issue

a snippet of autoloading that works perfectly fine on 5.3 is not working on 7, it is giving warnings faulire to open stream, no such file or directory

here is what is on my index

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

# the first calls an autoloader for namespacing (Klein), the second is from class names (like our custom database class)
spl_autoload_register('namespaceautoload');
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

and here is what is in my auloload.php file

```
function namespaceautoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    include $fileName;
}   


function autoload($class_name) 
    {
        //class directories
        $directorys = array(
            'classes/',
            'models/',
            'classes/other',
            'module1/classes/'
        );

        //for each directory
        foreach($directorys as $directory)
        {
            //see if the file exsists, have tried is_file() as well
            if(file_exists($directory.$class_name . '.php'))
            {
                include($directory.$class_name . '.php');
                //only require the class once, so quit after to save effort (if you got more, then name them something else 
                return;
            }            
        }
    }
```

any suggestions? I am not sure where to even start diagnosing this, it has to be path related?

classes are simply named, theres only 3 , database.php, sessions.php and ldap.php